# Convert Char field to Date field and remove time from the field name

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

I am using the following command to remove the time from the date field:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FieldValue,101) FROM table
```

`FieldValue` is a char field, but has a date i.e. `2012-09-30  00:00:00`

The above command returns `2012-09-30`, but I need it to be `09/30/2012`

Any idea what I need to add to the command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove time from datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279849/how-to-remove-time-from-datetime)

Comment: It is not exactly the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use format()

```
format(Fields!YourField.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```