# Format Last date not picking up specific formatting

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to get the most recent date from my `AuthAmounts` dataset in a `MM/dd/yyyy` format but it refuses to strip off the time value. I've tried every permutation I can think of, including the following:

```
=Format(Last(Fields!CustAuthorizationDate.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy"), "AuthAmounts")
=Last(Format(Fields!CustAuthorizationDate.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy"), "AuthAmounts")
=Format(Last(Fields!CustAuthorizationDate.Value,"AuthAmounts"), "MM/dd/yyyy")
=Last(Format(Fields!CustAuthorizationDate.Value,"AuthAmounts"), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

In every case, I get back something like `10/26/2010 12:00:00 AM`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Assuming `AuthAmounts` is your dataset the third one should've worked. Are you sure you deployed before testing? you can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281221/convert-char-field-to-date-field-and-remove-time-from-the-field-name/14281280#14281280

Comment: Strange.  Thanks eestein.  Based on your recommendation, I reverted to the third option above.  Saved. CLOSED SSRS 2005 Designer, reopened and loaded  the report and it works.  Not sure why I had to close and re-open, but I'm pleased it is finally working!

Comment: Yes, SSRS has some misterious issues. :D

Comment: Its important to apply the SQL Service packs to the machine running BIDS / Visual Studio, especially for SQL 2005.

Comment: Good to hear your problem was solved @DJGray! Please consider posting your solution as an answer so it's easy for others to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the discussion above in SSRS 2005 (BIDS), the user must sometimes save, close, and reopen the solution for the code changes to actually work.  As frustrating as this is, it is far LESS frustrating than having properly formatted expressions be repeatedly rejected by the system and not know why that is!

Answer (score 0):

If your formatting it in the report builder you need to do this in the table itself not the query or expression.

Remember that the SSRS service is smarter than everyone else ;) as such the service has a default date format of date and time. I get this all the time by default and you need to physically change the printed format not the expression or dataset query.