# SQL command for TSM archives

Tags: sql

Trying to run a select command that will show all my archives from a certain date. I can do this but the output has many entries for each archive as the date changes by the second. I only want archives by date format and not the time format. Using distinct does not work either.

Here is my command

```
select DISTINCT NODE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, ARCHIVE_DATE from ARCHIVES where ARCHIVE_DATE >= '2016-05-19' order by ARCHIVE_DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip time from your ARCHIVE_DATE. See [how to remove time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279849/how-to-remove-time-from-datetime) for your database specifics. Eg. in Oracle you would write:

```
select DISTINCT NODE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, TRUNC(ARCHIVE_DATE)
from ARCHIVES
where ARCHIVE_DATE >= '2016-05-19'
order by TRUNC(ARCHIVE_DATE)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for Roman. Thanks for your fast help.