# How to convert current time to date without time in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I want to select data where the operation_date between '01-Jan-2016' and yesterday. I used code as follows:

```
select *
where operation_date between '01-Jan-2016' and sysdate-1
from TABLE
```

But sysdate returns both date and time. Therefore, the above output includes all the data between '01-Jan-2016' and say, 14 Nov-2017 09:50:51. I only want the data before today. How to convert current time to date without time? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279849/how-to-remove-time-from-datetime)

Comment: TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd-MON-yyyy')

Comment: which DBMS are you using? The answer varies according to that.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: oracle developer

Comment: Thanks Jean Doux ! That's the method what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are looking for `trunc()`.

**Example**

```
SELECT sysdate - 1 AS current_Date_Time
    ,trunc(sysdate) - 1 AS CURRENT_DATE1
    ,trunc(sysdate - 1) AS CURRENT_DATE2
FROM dual
```

*Result*

```
CURRENT_DATE_TIME       CURRENT_DATE1         CURRENT_DATE2
----------------------------------------------------------
13.11.2017 18:08:41     13.11.2017 00:00:00   13.11.2017 00:00:00
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/WEPU18146)**

So the correct query will be as below.

```
SELECT *
WHERE operation_date BETWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' -- ANSI Date Literal
        AND trunc(sysdate - 1)
FROM TABLE
```

OR

```
SELECT *
WHERE operation_date BETWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' -- ANSI Date Literal
        AND trunc(sysdate) - 1
FROM TABLE
```