# How do I remove the date from a datetime stamp in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Very quick question, if I have a field, for example closed_date, which has a datetime, i.e.

```
01-JAN-19 09.00.00.000000000
```

And I would like to only look at cases closed between 09:00am and 10:00am each day, whats the syntax? How do I trunc the field just to time and only pull through cases which were closed each day between the 9am and 10am?

Many thanks

Comment: You have a _column_ named closed_date. A timestamp has the _fields_ hour, minutes etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279849/how-to-remove-time-from-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the hour portion alone; as you have a timestamp you can extract the hour number:

```
where extract(hour from closed_date) = 9
```

That will find rows there time is on or after 09:00:00, and *before* (not including) 10:00:00.

---

Usually when looking at data in a time period like 'between 9 and 10' you don't actually want to include the upper limit, because if you were also looking at data 'between 10 and 11' then data at exactly 10:00:00 would be included in both, which probably isn't what was intended. So it's common for date/time comparisons to use `>=` and `<` instead of `between`; you could also do this with a string comparison which you might consider clearer:

```
where to_char(closed_date, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '09:00:00'
and to_char(closed_date, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '10:00:00'
```

or slightly more simply

```
where to_char(closed_date, 'HH24') >= '09'
and to_char(closed_date, 'HH24') < '10'
```

which in this case, as it's a single hour, is the same as:

```
where to_char(closed_date, 'HH24') = '09'
```

but then as you are only looking at the hour part anyway, extracting that as a number simplifies it even more (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a condition to filter a timestamp column based on its hour part. There are various ways to extract date parts from a timestamp, here is a solution that uses TO_CHAR :

```
TO_CHAR(closed_date, 'hh24') = '09'
```

This will match on timestamps whose time is higher than or equal to 9 AM and strictly smaller than 10 AM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extract function from oracle

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp_col_value) AS CURRENT_HOUR
FROM DUAL;
```

Note that the extract function only works in certain combinations of MONTH/DAY/HOUR and date types. [See here for more details.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639)

If you want to extract a hour from a datetime, you need to convert it to a timestamp first, i.e.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS CURRENT_HOUR 
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select regexp_Replace('01-JAN-19 09.00.00.000000000','\d+-\w+-\d+ ') from dual
```

But if You want to search between hours, try `EXTRACT`, f.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  to_char(your_column,
               'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff a.m.',
               'nls_date_language=american') in (9,10)
```

Updated answer. without nls_Date_language parameter, hour 9 o' clock could be also 9.pm and that is 21.

Comment: Your edited answer isn't using extract any more; and you're now comparing a sting with many elements with numbers which I don't think you meant to do. But in any case neither extract or the `hh`/`hh24` models are NLS-dependent and your model doesn't have any date-language-dependent elements except the superfluous am/pm indicator. Using `extract(hour ...)` or `to_char()` with `hh24` will always give 9 for 9am and 21 for 9pm.

Comment: You compare a string of `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff a.m.'` (e.g. "2018-02-27 15:30:00.11 a.m.") with `IN (9,10)` - for sure this will fail. Also `hh24` in combination with `a.m.` is useless.