# Right outer join with multiple where conditions

Tags: java, python, sql, jython

I'm having some issues returning any results from my SQL query. I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with the WHERE condition.

I want only certain RULE_ID's to be returned. I identify the RULE_ID by it's RULE_NAME in TABLE1. I then join TABLE1 and TABLE2 and say if the column DATE for the RULE_ID is equal to 05-MAR-20 and the column COLUMN3 is not null, return the RULE_ID.

At the moment I'm not getting any results with this query and I'm not entirely sure why. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: COLUMN3 is in TABLE2 but not in TABLE1. I'm not getting an error, just no results are showing when I think I should be getting some. If I remove the `AND (TABLE2.DATE = '05-MAR-20')` I get several results. Not sure why this is...

```
sql_query = """
            SELECT TABLE1.RULE_ID, TABLE2.RULE_ID
            FROM TABLE1
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2
            ON (TABLE1.RULE_ID = TABLE2.RULE_ID)
            WHERE (TABLE1.RULE_NAME = 'TEST1' OR TABLE1.RULE_NAME = 'TEST2')  
            AND (TABLE2.DATE = '05-MAR-20')
            AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL
            """
```

Comment: What exactly is the error ?

Comment: When I run the query I get no result. The query finds nothing, when it should actually return 2 numbers

Comment: what is COLUMN3? I only see two columns.

Comment: It would be great if you could share a sample data and also the error

Comment: edited the question. COLUMN3 is in TABLE2 but not TABLE1 (DATE as well is only in TABLE2).

Comment: Could you please check date format in table2? and try to select items from table 2 filtered only by date? e.g. SELECT * from Table2 WHERE TABLE2.DATE = '05-MAR-20'

Comment: date format in oracle sql developer is DD-MMM-YY. I tried to execute a query like in your message and got no result. @elvira.genkel

Comment: @says could you please try change condition for date with TABLE2.DATE = TO_DATE('05-MAR-20', 'DD-MMM-YY')

Comment: That gives me an 'ORA-01821: date format not recognized' error @elvira.genkel

Comment: @says sorry incorrect date format mask. should be 'DD-MON-YY' : TABLE2.DATE = TO_DATE('05-MAR-20', 'DD-MON-YY') OR you can use another format to avoid month name collision: to_date('05-03-2020','DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: can you share your table structure with some sample data ?

Comment: I can't sorry @Ahnaf

Comment: Still no results @elvira.genkel. I'm thinking maybe this is an issue with Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: @says according to results you've provided the issue in date comparison. It is necessary to find a working way to select data from 2nd table by date. I have no additional ideas, sorry

Comment: All good! Thanks for your help @elvira.genkel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.  Much easier to follow the logic ("keep all rows in the first table".  Then move appropriate filtering to the `ON` clause):

```
SELECT TABLE1.RULE_ID, TABLE2.RULE_ID
FROM TABLE2 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1
      ON TABLE1.RULE_ID = TABLE2.RULE_ID AND
         TABLE1.RULE_NAME IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')   
WHERE TABLE2.DATE = DATE '2020-03-05' AND TABLE2.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm still having an issue with the DATE clause. When I remove the DATE condition I get results, however when it's in there I get no results

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've seen this post yet (or are even still trying to solve this issue lol) but: [how to remove time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279849/how-to-remove-time-from-datetime)

If I understand the post above correctly, there may be different way to call the date part of the date-time field depending on the format of the field and the interface you are using to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue - the dates are timestamped. In the dB, the date just says, DD-MON-YY, but when I return the dates I also have DD-MON-YY, HH:MM:SS.0. Just have to find a way now to get rid of the timestamp and just have the date.